# Buying flat based on historical data

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("past.csv")
df.info()

print() 

town_unique = df[['town']].drop_duplicates()
print('List of towns:')
print(*town_unique['town'], sep = "\n")

town_choice = str(input('Enter a town from above: ')).upper()

for town_choice in df.columns[10:].values:
    print(f'The price range of flats in {town_choice} is between ${df[town_choice].min():,.0f} and ${df[town_choice].max():,.0f}.')

print()

min_price = int(input('Enter a minimum flat price: '))
max_price = int(input('Enter a maximum flat price: '))
print('The types of flats available are:')
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 80374 entries, 0 to 80373
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column               Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------               --------------  -----  
 0   month                80374 non-null  object 
 1   town                 80374 non-null  object 
 2   flat_type            80374 non-null  object 
 3   block                80374 non-null  object 
 4   street_name          80374 non-null  object 
 5   storey_range         80374 non-null  object 
 6   floor_area_sqm       80374 non-null  float64
 7   flat_model           80374 non-null  object 
 8   lease_commence_date  80374 non-null  int64  
 9   remaining_lease      80374 non-null  object 
 10  resale_price         80374 non-null  float64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(1), object(8)
memory usage: 6.7+ MB

List of towns:
TOWN A
TOWN B
TOWN C
TOWN D
TOWN E

Enter a town from above: TOWN A
The price range of flats in **resale_price** is between **$140,000** and **$1,258,000**.

Enter a minimum flat price: 100000
Enter a maximum flat price: 20000
The types of flats available are:
```

1. After entering TOWN A, the input came out as **resale price** iso TOWN A. The min and max values reflected are the min and max of all towns iso the input town. How can I get the min and max of the input town only?
2. I need to list the available flat types based on the town input and the value of the min and max flat price that the user have keyed.
3. User will then select the room type and a list of the past transaction will be listed out in the table as so:
   'No.' 'Block' 'Street Name' 'Storey Range' 'Size(sq m)' 'Price($)'

Can anyone help? I am so lost.

Comment: welcome to SO! re: "resale price" iso "TOWN A": i don't know the language but maybe 'flats in {town_choice} is between' should be 'flats in ${town_choice} is between' ? (with a dollar sign)

Comment: please edit the question to add the missing bit after 'print('The types of flats available are:')'

also, can you include the input data (CSV file) or a reference to it?

Comment: Thank you for the welcome! :)

Here is the link to the excel - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N9k9k6xB-Q8JBIEedmxfWpjotZtyb2uS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: and this is the link to the desired output - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MmgwDEbkVBhfdGZrVeheAWdCjkKFXDrl/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You weren't using `town_choice` to filter the dataset. I do that below to create `one_town`, containing just the rows from the town picked.
2. In creating `flat_types`, I used a compound binary expression to filter for just the rows in the price range, and `.loc` to select just the `flat_type` column of those rows.
3. I'm leaving the 3rd part, 'user selects a type, all flats of that type are listed', for you. It'll use the same techniques.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("past.csv")
df.info()

print() 

town_unique = df[['town']].drop_duplicates()
print('List of towns:')
print(*town_unique['town'], sep = "\n")

# hardcode the choice to make edit/run/debug iteration faster
#town_choice = str(input('Enter a town from above: ')).upper()
town_choice = "HOUGANG"

one_town = df[df["town"] == town_choice]
print(f'The price range of flats in {town_choice} is between ${one_town["resale_price"].min():,.0f} and ${one_town["resale_price"].max():,.0f}.')

print()

# hardcode the choices to make edit/run/debug iteration faster
min_price = 383500 # int(input('Enter a minimum flat price: '))
max_price = 384500 # int(input('Enter a maximum flat price: '))

flat_types = one_town.loc[(one_town["resale_price"] >= min_price) & (one_town["resale_price"] <= max_price), "flat_type"].drop_duplicates()

print('The types of flats available are:')
print(*flat_types, sep = "\n")
print()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I managed to get it! :D

Comment: glad that helped! it was a fun exercise. feel free to 'accept' my answer so i get a few points of rep..

Comment: Btw, would you be able to help? I tried to print the table out for the selected flats but I only wanted selected columns. 

Am i missing out something here? 

`flat_list = df.loc[(df['town'] == town_choice) & (df['flat_type'] == desired_flat) & (df['resale_price'] >= min_price) & (df['resale_price'] <= max_price)]
df1 = df[['block', 'street_name', 'storey_range','floor_area_sqm','resale_price']]
print(flat_list)`